# Where does windows store network interface profiles? How can I reset them?

Tags: windows-10, networking, windows-registry, ethernet, windows-networking

Here is my current situation. I have multiple copies of the same device (these are USB devices), they are all exactly the same (same MAC address, etc), and they get recognized as ethernet adapters (ethernet 1, ethernet 2, etc).

However, I run into an issue with `Ethernet 2` **only**. Meaning I don't have any issues with ethernet 3, 4, 5, etc. Just to make sure it wasn't specific to a certain device I swapped the order of the devices ( I plugged in what was Ethernet 5 first and jumbled up the order of plugging them in) and still, the device that used to be Ethernet 4 was now Ethernet 2 and it still I had issues with that network interface profile. I understand that the name of the network adapters doesn't actually affect anything, I assume Windows "caches" some settings somewhere specific to that Ethernet 2 profile.

I was wondering how I could "reset" any settings related to those network adapters.

I believed I messed up a setting for Ethernet 2 so I want to reset it to a clean slate. I tried removing registry entries under `interfaces`, restarted networking, cleared ARP cache, and still no progress. Any help would be appreciated. In case anyone is wondering the thing that doesn't work with the ethernet 2 profile is network bridging.

Comment: do you mean `ncpa.cpl`?

Comment: @Albin Yes, I mean ncpa.cpl

Answer (score 0):

You can view all your network adapters via the control panel. Easiest way to start the appropriate applet is via command line: `ncpa.cpl`

There you can take several actions like renaming, changing the settings, bridging adapters, deleting them etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response but this wasn't what I was asking for. Bridging wasn't working with Ethernet 2, I was wondering where Windows caches the data for these adapters in relation to perhaps their hardware ID or MAC address. Perhaps in the registry somewhere.

Comment: @Sparky if there is a adapter installed you it should appear in the applet. There you can do anything you like. Renaming or bridging were just examples, you can do several other things as well, I assume you mean to delete it, which you can do there, but I'm not sure. You will need to clarify what exactly you want to do. I tried to read your question several times but I still don't get it.